# URL Encryption in MVC Application (in common settings)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I am working on MVC 3.0 application where I want to secure my URL like `http://myapplication/Project/edit/12` so any one can change this ID. So I wan to secure (encrypt) this URL.

and my application very large near about 40-50 pages so add encryption and decryption logic in each view and controller's each action that is not a good idea.

So I want to add some thing in my global.aspx.cs, so how can I achive this?

you answer will be really appreciable.

Comment: What do you mean _encrypt this url_? A use can type whatever they want in the browser address bar. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Encrypting the url is not going to secure it. You have to check in your controller action if the authenticated user has the right to view that page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110078/mvc3-url-parameters-avoiding-malicious-attacks-security-flaws